# Return type of a Function which returns a Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below function which returns another `function`, where the `getFirstPhoneNo()` would return a `string`.

```
get phones() {
    if (this._patientData && this._patientData.getPatientPrimaryAddress) {
        return this._patientData.getFirstPhoneNo();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Below is my `interface` for `patientData`

```
export interface IPatient {
    getFirstPhoneNo: Function
}
```

What should be my return type for phones? Should it be a type of `Ipatient` or `Function` or a `Function which returns string`

Comment: Where is `function` which returns another `function`?

Comment: @Satpal that's `getFirstPhoneNo()`I think, which returns a `string`

Comment: You see the phones() which returns getFirstPhoneNo

Comment: `phones()` returns a string (the return value of `getFirstPhoneNo`) or a boolean

Comment: @Shane, Its returning the output of `getFirstPhoneNo()` which you said will return `string`. So it either returns string of boolean

Comment: `return this._patientData.getFirstPhoneNo();` calls `getFirstPhoneNo()` and returns that value. `return this._patientData.getFirstPhoneNo;` would return the function

Comment: @Shane you can either combine the return types with an "or", `|`, or just return type `any`. There isn't a correct answer here I think, it's opinion based..

Comment: return type for `phones` should be same as return type of `getFirstPhoneNo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPatient is defined as such

```
export interface IPatient {
   getFirstPhoneNo: () => () => string
}
```

which means that getFirstPhoneNo is a function which returns a function which returns a string.
So `get phones` returns either a boolean or a function which returns a string. This can be translated to a return type of `boolean | () => string`. This return type is not very useful because it only has properties which both of the types `boolean` and `() => string` share.

One possibility would be to change your code like this:

```
get phones() {
  if (this._patientData && this._patientData.getPatientPrimaryAddress) {
    return this._patientData.getFirstPhoneNo();
  }
  return () => '';
}
```

This changes the interface of `get phones` to `() => () => string` and but also allows you to do checks if the phone number is set (because an empty string evaluates to false)

Another easier approach would be to do the method call already in the `get phone` function and only return the phone number

```
   get phones() {
      if (this._patientData && this._patientData.getPatientPrimaryAddress) {
        return this._patientData.getFirstPhoneNo()();
      }
      return null;
    }
```